# Nested Luigi tasks do not appear in execution summary

Tags: python, workflow, luigi

I plan on using Luigi to write a reproducible and failure-resistant hyperparameter-tuning task. Therefore I call my `class TrainOneModel` multiple times within the "parent" `class HParamOptimizer`.

To simplify things here is an easier hello world version:

```py
import luigi

# Child class
class HelloTask(luigi.Task):
    name = luigi.parameter.Parameter(default='Luigi')

    def run(self):
        print(f'Luigi says: Hello {self.name}!')

# Parent class
class ManyHellos(luigi.Task):

    def run(self):
        names = ['Marc', 'Anna', 'John']
        for name in names:
            hello = HelloTask(name=name)
            hello.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run(['ManyHellos', '--workers', '1', '--local-scheduler'])
```

Running the script with `python filename.py` works and the progress looks :). Names are also printed as expected, however, the execution summary only shows that `ManyHellos` ran:

```
Scheduled 1 tasks of which:
* 1 ran successfully:
    - 1 ManyHellos()
```

Is there a possibility of including the child `class HelloTask` to view how things are progressing in the central scheduling visualizer?

Thanks, BBQuercus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not shown because you're executing their run() manually instead of going through the scheduler. The luigi way to do it would be more like this:

```
import luigi


# Child class
class HelloTask(luigi.Task):
    name = luigi.parameter.Parameter(default='Luigi')

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as fout:
            fout.write(f'Luigi says: Hello {self.name}!')

    def output(self):
        # An output target is needed for the scheduler to verify whether
        # the task was run.
        return luigi.LocalTarget(f'./names/{self.name}.txt')


# Parent class
class ManyHellos(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        names = ['Marc', 'Anna', 'John']
        for name in names:
            yield HelloTask(name=name)  # dynamically schedules a HelloTask


if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run(['ManyHellos', '--workers', '1', '--local-scheduler'])
```

which leads to

```
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 4 tasks of which:
* 4 ran successfully:
    - 3 HelloTask(name=Anna,John,Marc)
    - 1 ManyHellos()

This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing dependencies
```

when executed. Note that you could also yield multiple tasks at once, with `yield [HelloTask(name) for name in names]`